# ¿Cómo asignar nuevos valores al campo id?

Tags: r, dataframe

Tengo el siguiente extracto de un dataframe:

```
     id   hijos   edad
1   AB22    2      31
2   AB25    1      27
3   AB25    1      25
4   AB25    3      33
5   AB50    2      40
6   AB35    1      37
7   AB35    1      39
8   AB40    1      41
```

Tengo que comprobar si existen registros duplicados en el campo **id**. La idea es asignar un nuevo **id** a los registros duplicados (sin repetirlos), de manera que su parte numérica tiene que ser un valor superior al máximo valor numérico del campo **id**. En el ejemplo, el máximo valor es **50** (registro 5). Por lo tanto, el dataframe podría quedar de la siguiente manera (aquí añado un número más, pero puede ser cualquier valor, siempre que sea mayor al máximo):

```
     id   hijos   edad
1   AB22    2      31
2   AB25    1      27
3   AB51    1      25
4   AB52    3      33
5   AB50    2      40
6   AB35    1      37
7   AB53    1      39
8   AB40    1      41
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer esto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Con R base puedes resolverlo así:

```
duplicados <- duplicated(df$id)
id_num <- ifelse(duplicados, cumsum(duplicados) + max(as.numeric(substring(df$id, 3))), 0)
df$new_id <- ifelse(duplicados, paste0(substring(df$id, 1, 2),id_num), df$id)
```

Básicamente `duplicated()` nos retorna `TRUE` cuando el `id` esta duplicado, luego simplemente generamos un numerador para estos casos que suma 1 al valor más alto de la parte numérica del `id`, luego simplemente es pegar las dos partes del id solo en el caso de los duplicados.

Con una lógica similar, si estás cómodo con `tidyverse` podrías hacer:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(duplicado = duplicated(id)) %>% 
  separate(id, into = c("id1", "id2"), sep=2, remove=FALSE) %>% 
  mutate(dup_num = ifelse(duplicado, cumsum(duplicado), 0),
         new_id = ifelse(duplicado, paste0(id1,max(as.numeric(id2)) + dup_num), paste0(id1, id2)) 
         ) %>% 
  select(id, new_id, hijos, edad)
```

Answer (score 3):

No se sera la mejor opción, o me di muchas vueltas pero asi logre resolver tu pregunta:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(
    aux = as.numeric(duplicated(id)),
    parte_suma = cumsum(aux),
    parte_numerica = as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9]", "", id)),
    parte_caracter = gsub("[0-9]", "", id),
    id = ifelse(
      aux == 0,
      paste0(parte_caracter, parte_numerica),
      paste0(parte_caracter, max(parte_numerica) + parte_suma)
    )
  ) %>%
  select(-aux, -parte_suma, -parte_numerica, -parte_caracter)
```

1. crear una variable auxiliar que toma valor 1 cuando el id esta duplicado y 0 cuando no
2. separar el id en una parte numérica y en una parte carácter
3. cree una variable que se llama parte suma, que corresponde a la suma acumulada de los valores duplicados
4. finalmente crear la variable id, que es concatenar la parte carácter con la parte numérica cuando aux == 0 , es decir, cuando no esta duplicada, y para cuando esta duplicada, concatenemos la parte caracter con el maximo de la parte numerica y le sumamos la suma acumulada para asegurarnos tener un id mayor al maximo pero que a la vez no se repita.